# Replace UBound in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core

I am porting an existing library to .net standard 2.0 and i think i have reached my last error(hopefully) I need to change UBound which from what i am reading means Array.Length?

```
 If aryTemp Is Nothing Then
                ReDim aryTemp(0)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve aryTemp(UBound(aryTemp) + 1)
            End If
            aryTemp(UBound(aryTemp)) = _TransactionItems(i)
```

Would my code then be  `ReDim Preserve aryTemp((aryTemp).Length + 1)` ?
How would i change UBound since I am not able to port it to .net standard?

Comment: Get rid of the array and use a `List(of T)` and you wont need that awful `ReDim Preserve` at all

Comment: @Plutonix Cool, what would that look like?

Comment: If, say, the type of elements of your array is `Integer`, then you could write `Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)` and then you could continuously call `lst.Add(_TransactionItems(i))` until your computer runs out of memory.

Comment: Not that I disagree but, to answer the question as asked, an array has a `GetUpperBound` method.

Comment: "UBound which from what i am reading means Array.Length" No. In vb arrays are declared arr(UBound); UBound being the highest index in the array. The Array.Length is the number of elements; one more than the UBound. In C# arrays are declared arr(Length)

Comment: If you use a list then you should be able to replace all that code with `aryTemp.Add(TransactionItems(i))`

Comment: @DavidWilson could i see what the code would look like?

Comment: Instead of `Dim aryTemp as TransactionItem()` or whatever class you use, Try Dim aryTemp As New List(Of TransactionItem). To add items, instead of using tyour code sample, just replace it with the one line in my previous comment. Much easier :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is VB.NET equivalent of your VB6 imported code:

```
If aryTemp Is Nothing Then
    Redim aryTemp(0)
Else
    ReDim Preserve aryTemp(aryTemp.Length)
End If
aryTemp(aryTemp.Length -1 ) = _TransactionItems(i)
```

This code expects, that LBound of this array is allways 0. It could be something else in VB6.

I'm not sure how Redim Preserve will work with .NET Standard.

Changing this array to `List(Of Integer)` is much better idea as noted in comments. `Redim Preserve` should be very, very rare piece of code nowadays for very special scenarios only.